# Can I remove the lambda from this Elm expression?

Tags: lambda, higher-order-functions, elm, combinators

Here is a complete Elm script, that places a bunch of tuples into an HTML `<ul>` element.

```
import Html exposing (ul, li, text)
import List exposing (map)

values = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]

main =
  ul [] (values |> map (\t -> li [] [text(toString(t))]))
```

I like to use the `|>` or other higher-order operators where possible, but given the relatively deep nesting of `t` within the expression above, I've not been able to figure out a nice way to express this line. Are there higher order operators in Elm that would allow the `\t` lambda to be unnecessary?

I realize it might be more readable to use the lambda, but was wondering what kind of combinators should be employed here, given that the `toString` call is inside a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to avoid the lambda it's easier to start with `values` and "pipeline" it through, transforming it a step at a time to get it to the final form you want:

```elm
import Html exposing (ul, li, text)
import List exposing (map, repeat)

values = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9)]

main
  = map toString values
  |> map text
  |> map (repeat 1)
  |> map (li [])
  |> ul []
```

Comment: Awesome, `repeat 1` was the key. I'm favoring at the moment `main = ul [] (map (li [] << repeat 1 << text << toString) values)` The other way would of course be `main = values |> map (toString >> text >> repeat 1 >> li []) |> ul [] `